How to add an image or field to the user's My Orders tab in section Order Information in magento2.4.5
Hello everyone I have customized the payment method and I want to add a field to save the QR code image of that payment method in the part I highlighted in red in the image.

Can any one tell me how to achieve?
Thanks in advance
